# Amazon s3 download instead of browser with URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, browser, amazon-s3

I currently have multiple link to PDF file that are stored in my s3 public bucket so i can access them from anywhere without being logged or whatever

When i open one of the link it open up in my internet browser and i can see my PDF file.

I know there's the solution to set the Content-Disposition to attachment so that when you're using the URL the file is downloading.

Is there a way the enter in the URL the content-disposition to attachement so i have certain link that open in the browser and other that download automatically ?

I hope i'm clear enough .. Thanks

Comment: Did you set the `Content-Type` correctly, e.g. `application/pdf` when you stored the files in S3?